# How to to hide action bar (Theme.Holo) if Android version below 3.0

Tags: android

I notice the action bar (Theme.Holo) looks cool only in android 3.0 or heigher, but it doesn't like nice on for example Android 2.3.

is there away to show the action bar ( Theme.Holo) based on Android version?

Comment: Couldn't you use two layouts and set one for Pre 3.0 and one for Post 3.0?

Comment: I prefer if I do it progrmatically, for example ,i check android version, if below 3.0 , remove bar.

Comment: There is no action bar on Android 2.3, unless you take specific steps to add third-party code that implements one (e.g., ActionBarSherlock).

Comment: I'm sorry ...  Imeant the tile bar that appear on Android like 2.3, how do I remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the ActionBar wasn't added until Android 3.0 (API level 11) so any version of Android lower than that will have a title bar, not an action bar.

The ActionBar is not yet a part of the official compatibility library, so in the mean time, the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library will allow you to have an ActionBar that looks the same across all API versions.

If you want to hide the ActionBar completely just add adding android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar to the activities in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks ... how would I add android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar progmtically depending on Android version.

Comment: I don't think you can add that attribute programatically, but ActionBarSherlock would handle the different Android versions for you, giving your app the same nice ActionBar across all API versions

Are you just trying to be able to hide the ActionBar completely for anything lower than Android 3.0? and show it for Android 3.0+?

Comment: Yes,but to be precise, I would like to hide the "title bar" on Android lower than 3.0 and keep the "Action bar" on 3+

Comment: I'm trying to explain that you can have the Action Bar on Android < 3.0 and on 3.0+.  However, if you don't want that, you can set themes based on the version of Android, which should be able to achieve what you're looking for.  See this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme

Comment: Thank you ... the link explain exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5):

The action bar requires API 11 minimum. If you want to remove it programatically though you can use hide() in the code for that activity.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Not really sure what it would show for anything below 3.0, but it seems like the best place to start.

Edit:

You can check the SDK version at run time with the Build constants

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) { //checks if its lower than Honeycomb
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... but how would I check Android version?

Comment: I guess it must be greater than or equal to (">=") symbol instead of less than( < ) symbol.. and thanks it helped me :)