# can not remove title bar in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-styles, android-actionbaractivity

i want to remove title on top of my Activity. i tried this two way they work but not in api level 8.

1:

```
<style name="NOtitleTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> </style>
```

2:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

any idea why this does not work on `api 8`?

once i managed to remove it in `api 8`, but i do not remember how.

---

**EDIT:**

**Solved!** the problem was     `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` does not work on API 8, and also `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` does not work, but   `actionBar.hide()` works , the reason that getSupportActionBar() returns null was using one of the two option before, i just forget to remove both. when i remove one i add other(what a a stupid !)
thanks all! (sorry for bad English)

Comment: i use ActionBarActivity,maybe important.

Comment: check this link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222323/how-to-to-hide-action-bar-theme-holo-if-android-version-below-3-0

Comment: not related ,no help.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13523319/3292795

Answer (score 10):

**Add to your Manifest:**

for full screen:

```
        <activity
        android:name="youtpackagename.activityname"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

or (hide title alone)

```
       <activity
        android:name="youtpackagename.activityname"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

or else use below code before `setContentView` method .

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

or

```
{
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); or getSupportActionBar();
  actionBar.hide();
}
```

**Edit:**

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Its working fine below api 8 also.. i hope this will help you

Comment: i tried all, i created i custom theme with no NoTitleBar , but does not work. i get no error but Title is still on the top.

Comment: @arsenal dont create any theme and all just add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in your activity tag (manifest).. its android default theme

Comment: i cant add theme because i use ActionBarActivity, when i change theme i get error, except using Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: getSupportActionBar() returns null.

Comment: @arsenal good finally find the answer!! but in earlier itself i mention both

Answer (score 3):

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

         <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> <!-- Hides the status bar -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

add this in your styles xml to your AppTheme.

And

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

}
```

Add this to your activity. Use ActionBarActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: getSupportActionBar() returns null.

Comment: have u removed this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: You don't have to use anything else. I have tried it with api 8 and with 19. Its working for both of them.

Comment: remove this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: i removed this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); but still 
 
getSupportActionBar() returns null.

Comment: i did, i forget to remove both!

Answer (score 1):

To me the only way that worked was doing this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Only by saying that my theme was a child of NoActionBar, I managed to eliminate the actionBar. All the other ways failed. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

use requestWindowFeature method before setContentView method .

Comment: i know, i use it before setContentView method but nothing happen.

Comment: in Activity     this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); works, i use ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your "workaround" (hiding the actionBar yourself) is the normal way. But google recommends to always hide the actionbar when the Title Bar is hidden. Have a look here: 
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

If your build version is less than 16 use it as given below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
...
```

}

Comment: i tried to hide actionBar but getActionBarSupport returns null, seems i have no ActionBar,

Comment: Post your full oncreate method ...And must use the above code before the setContentView

Comment: FULLSCREEN is not my problem, my activity is already FULLSCREEN and is ok, the problem is the title.